# Multi-column MATCH/AGAINST with Hibernate (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to implement this SQL criteria:

```sql
MATCH(col1, col2, ..., colN) AGAINST ...
```

I have it working with a single column, configured as:

```java
// register the "function" in custom MySQL dialect
registerFunction("FULLTEXT_MATCH_BOOLEAN", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "MATCH(?1) AGAINST(?2 IN BOOLEAN MODE)"));


// implement the function
public Predicate fulltextMatch(Expression<String> searchText, Path<String> path)
{
    final var allArgs = new Expression<?>[]{
        path
        searchText,
    };

    return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(criteriaBuilder.function("FULLTEXT_MATCH_BOOLEAN", Double.class, allArgs), 0D);
}
```

However, as you can see, the call to `fulltextMatch` only supports a single column. I need to support 1-many columns but am not sure how to create a compound/multiple path. The goal is to be able to call this method as:

```java
keywordPredicates.add(h.fulltextMatch(keyword, colZ));       // single col
keywordPredicates.add(h.fulltextMatch(keyword, col1, col2)); // multiple cols
```

Here's the updated method with the missing piece:

```java
public Predicate fulltextMatch(Expression<String> searchText, Path<String> ...paths)
{
    final var allArgs = new Expression<?>[]{
        // TODO: get compound "list" of paths as single expression
        searchText,
    };

    return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(criteriaBuilder.function("FULLTEXT_MATCH_BOOLEAN", Double.class, allArgs), 0D);
```

I'd like to avoid having to register multiple functions, e.g. (bad):

```java
registerFunction("FULLTEXT_MATCH_BOOLEAN_1", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "MATCH(?1) AGAINST(?2 IN BOOLEAN MODE)"));
registerFunction("FULLTEXT_MATCH_BOOLEAN_2", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "MATCH(?1, ?2) AGAINST(?3 IN BOOLEAN MODE)"));
// and so on
```

Comment: I ended up using `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to aggregate the JSON blobs instead, since `JSON_ARRAYAGG` doesn't support `DISTINCT`. So this is not important to me any more, other than to just know how I could have done it.